# Using Boost 32 bit libraries on Windows with MinGW32 leads to undefined references

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cmake, mingw

My setup is the following: I have a CMake based C++ project on Windows. As compiler I use the MinGW 32 Bit compiler which is delivered by the Qt 5.7 release for Windows (MinGW 5.3.0). I use this compiler since it works with the generated Makefiles. The generator is "MinGW Makefiles". Other compilers like Clang for Windows were not able to compile the generated Makefiles, probably because a Windows version of Make was missing?

Since the manual compilation of Boost Libraries takes a long time I use the prebuild binaries (https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.62.0_b2/) for msvc14.0-32. I've setup the CMake variables etc. and the libraries for Boost Release are found. Strangely the debug libraries are not found, so I have to use the build type "Release" with CMake.

Here are some variables:

```
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is "Release"
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER is "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/g++.exe".
CMAKE_GENERATOR is "MinGW Makefiles"
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe"
BOOST_ROOT is "C:/local/boost_1_62_0_b2"
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR is "C:/local/boost_1_62_0_b2/lib32-msvc-14.0", Boost_COMPILER is "-vc140"
Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_DEBUG is "C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.0"
Boost_LIBRARY_DIR_RELEASE is "C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.0"
Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG is "Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND"
Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE is "C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.0/libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61.lib"
```

When I compile my project it generates many undefined references errors:

```
CMakeFiles\wc3libmpq.dir/objects.a(hash.cpp.obj):hash.cpp:(.text+0x559): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
CMakeFiles\wc3libmpq.dir/objects.a(hash.cpp.obj):hash.cpp:(.text+0x571): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, int> const&)'
CMakeFiles\wc3libmpq.dir/objects.a(hash.cpp.obj):hash.cpp:(.text+0x586): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
CMakeFiles\wc3libmpq.dir/objects.a(hash.cpp.obj):hash.cpp:(.text+0x59e): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, int> const&)'
CMakeFiles\wc3libmpq.dir/objects.a(hash.cpp.obj):hash.cpp:(.text+0x78b): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
CMakeFiles\wc3libmpq.dir/objects.a(hash.cpp.obj):hash.cpp:(.text+0x7a7): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, int> const&)'
```

These are some of them. I guess it does not work since they were compiled with a different compiler (vc140) and not the MinGW 32 from Qt but I did not find any prebuild Boost Libraries with MinGW32 for Windows.

Ideally, I'd like to setup the build with Clang 64 Bit but as I wrote the Generator "MinGW Makefiles" of CMake and the specified Make tool CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM with the value "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe" do not work with the CLang build for Windows. Qt 5 does not offer any MinGW 64 version. Besides the undefined references error might occur as well since Boost has been built with msvc.

So my questions are:

Is there a MinGW32 based build of the Boost Libraries for Windows somewhere which works with Qt's MinGW32 compiler?

OR which would be even more useful

Is there a CMake Generator and Make tool which work together with the 64 Bit CLang on Windows AND a build of the Boost Libraries for Windows which does also work with CLang? In this case I'd also need a Qt 5.7 Windows build which works with CLang and is 64 bit since the MinGW build of Qt 5.7 is 32 bit.

I would like to avoid any effort to compile any dependency libraries myself on Windows.

**edit:**

After compiling the Boost Libraries by myself with Cygwin (GCC) I still get undefined references to the Boost Libraries. I link to the static libraries (.a) files:

```
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x8d4): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x8d4): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x964): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x964): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0xae8): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0xae8): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0xb08): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0xb08): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0xb22): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0xb22): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0xf19): more undefined references to `boost::system::system_category()' follow
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0xf19): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0xf40): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x1019): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x1040): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x1119): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x1140): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x47bc): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x4bcb): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x4d69): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x4d92): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x4db5): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x4e9c): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x4ef6): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o):operations.cpp:(.text+0x4f38): more undefined references to `boost::system::system_category()' follow
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(bzip2.o):bzip2.cpp:(.text+0x327): undefined reference to `BZ2_bzDecompressEnd'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(bzip2.o):bzip2.cpp:(.text+0x341): undefined reference to `BZ2_bzCompressEnd'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(bzip2.o):bzip2.cpp:(.text+0x390): undefined reference to `BZ2_bzDecompressInit'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(bzip2.o):bzip2.cpp:(.text+0x3af): undefined reference to `BZ2_bzCompressInit'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(bzip2.o):bzip2.cpp:(.text+0x145): undefined reference to `BZ2_bzCompress'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(bzip2.o):bzip2.cpp:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `BZ2_bzDecompress'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(zlib.o):zlib.cpp:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `crc32'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(zlib.o):zlib.cpp:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `deflateReset'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(zlib.o):zlib.cpp:(.text+0x1c5): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(zlib.o):zlib.cpp:(.text+0x1e1): undefined reference to `inflateReset'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(zlib.o):zlib.cpp:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(zlib.o):zlib.cpp:(.text+0x407): undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(zlib.o):zlib.cpp:(.text+0x450): undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(zlib.o):zlib.cpp:(.text+0x174): undefined reference to `deflate'
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_iostreams.a(zlib.o):zlib.cpp:(.text+0x184): undefined reference to `inflate'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [src/mpq/libwc3libmpq.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [src/mpq/CMakeFiles/wc3libmpq.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

Strangely I don't get any undefined references for the unit test library of Boost. I have compiled the libraries using Cygwin's GCC and my library paths to Boost look like:

```
E:/Projekte/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.a
```

First I have compiled the iostreams library with cygwin:

```
./b2.exe -j4 toolset=gcc --with-iostreams -s BZIP2_SOURCE=E:/Projekte/wc3lib/windows/bzip2-1.0.6 -s ZLIB_SOURCE=E:/Projekte/wc3lib/windows/zlib-1.2.8 stage
```

The I compiled all other libraries:

```
./b2.exe -j4 toolset=gcc stage
```

These are my search instructions in CMake:

```
if (WIN32)
    add_definitions(-DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED=1)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
    include_directories("C:/Program Files/GnuWin32/include")
endif ()

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem serialization program_options iostreams regex REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Just build it. I'm not certain what you consider a "long time", but I just ran and timed a build of debug+release, static+dynamic (so 4 sets) of boost and it took 6.5 minutes. I bet you already wasted significantly more than that trying to avoid the work.

Comment: It took quite some time for me. The other problem is that the process does not work as expected. Boost Build uses the cygwin MinGW and not the MinGW from Qt. It says it cannot use my precompiled bzip2 and zlib libraries since they are incompatible. How can I specify the compiler path for Boost build? toolset=gcc selects the cygwin GCC automatically or my binaries are really incompatible.

Comment: I've compiled bzip2 and zlib with Boost now but get undefined references to the Boost libraries when compiling my project. "E:/Projects/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.a" is found and used in debug mode but I get lots of undefined references to it.

Comment: IIRC with both bzip2 and zlib you only need source code, the boost buildsystem will compile them itself.

Comment: Yes I did it this way in the end. I have other undefined references now. While it perfectly links to the unit test library I get undefined references from filesystem although I link to system as well.